# Show that $I(t),0\leq t\leq T$ is a martingale

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus, self-learning, martingales

> **Exercise 4.1** Suppose $M(t),0\leq t \leq T$ is a martingale with respect to some filtration $\mathcal{F}(t),0\leq t, \leq T$. Let $\Delta(t),0\leq t \leq T$, be a simple process adapted to $\mathcal{F}$ (i.e., there is a partition $\mathcal{\Pi}=\{t_0,t_1,\dots\,t_n\}$ of $[0,T]$ such that, for every $j$, $\Delta(t_j)$ is $\mathcal{F}(t_j)$-measurable and $\Delta(t)$ is a constant in $t$ on each subinterval $[t_j,t_j+1))$. For $t\in[t_k,t_{k+1})$, define the stochastic integral
> $$I(t)=\sum^{k-1}_{j=0}\Delta(t_j)[M(t_{j+1})-M(t_j)]+\Delta(t_k)[M(t)-M(t_k)].$$
> We think of $M(t)$ as the price of an asset at time $t$ and $\Delta(t_j)$ as the number of shares of the asset held by an investor between times $t_j$ and $t_{j+1}$. Then $I(t)$ is the capital gains that accrue to the investor between times $0$ and $t$. Show that $I(t),0\leq t\leq T$, is a martingale.
>
> Source: [Stochastic Calculus for Finance II by Steve Shreve, pg. 189](https://cms.dm.uba.ar/academico/materias/2docuat2016/analisis_cuantitativo_en_finanzas/Steve_ShreveStochastic_Calculus_for_Finance_II.pdf)

### My Work So Far

*Proof*. Set $t$ for any $s\lt t$ and we assume $s\in[t_m,t_{m-1}]$

- Case 1:$\ m=k$, thus
  $$I(t)-I(s)=\Delta_{t_k}(M_t-M_{t_k})-\Delta_{t_k}(M_s-M_{t_k})=\Delta_{t_k}(M_t-M_s)$$
  So,
  $$\mathbb{E}[I(t)-I(s)|\mathcal{F}_t]=\Delta_{t_k}\mathbb{E}[M_t-M_s|\mathcal{F}_s]=0$$
- Case 2:$\ m\lt k$, thus
  $$t_m\lt s \lt t_{m+1}\leq t_k\leq t \leq t_{k+1}$$
  So,
  \begin{align*}
  I(t)-I(s)&=\sum^{k-1}_{j=m}\Delta_{t_j}(M_{t_{j+1}}-M_{t_j})+\Delta_{t_k}(M_s-M_{t_k})-\Delta_{t_m}(M_s-M_{t_m})\\
  &=\sum^{k-1}_{j=m+1}\Delta_{t_j}(M_{t{_j+1}}-M_{t_j})+\Delta_{t_k}(M_t-M_{t_k})+\Delta_{t_m}(M_{t_{m+1}}-M_s).\\\\
  \end{align*}
  Therefore, we note that
  \begin{align*}
  &\mathbb{E}[I(t)-I(s)|\mathcal{F}_s]\\
  &=\sum^{k-1}_{j=m+1}\mathbb{E}[\Delta_{t_j}\mathbb{E}[M_{t_{j+1}}-M_{t_j}|\mathcal{F}_{t_j}]|\mathcal{F}_s]+\mathbb{E}[\Delta_{t_k}\mathbb{E}[M_t-M_{t_k}|\mathcal{F}_{t_k}]|\mathcal{F}_s]+\Delta_{t_m}\mathbb{E}[M_{t_{m+1}}-M_s|\mathcal{F}_s]\\
  &=0.\\
  \end{align*}
  When combined, we can conclude that $I(t)$ is a martingale. $\square$

Would this be correct? Is there a better way to prove this?

Comment: Please use parentheses, because right now you have $|M_{t_{j+1}} - M_{t_j}]$ which is highly confusing.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a hint about the parenthesis? I'm a beginning in stochastic calculus, so apologies in advance. Also, would this proof make sense?

Comment: Your proof looks good to me, though I haven’t checked it symbol by symbol. I think you followed the correct direction of proof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few typos (for example, in case 1 in the second line of equalities the first conditioning should be on $\mathcal{F}_s$; in case 2 you on the contrary use index $s$ instead of $t$ in the expression for $I(t)$ in the first line of equalities), but other than that everything is correct. I also don't think there is a better way to show it. If you are interested, the same way (though with omitting some details) is used to prove this statement in another book of Steven Shreve, namely "Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus" by I.Karatzas and S.Shreve (formula (2.13) on page 137 and its proof on page 138).